# cannot use res.state in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a problem like this. I am making a web application using angular and node js. In the back end I sending a response like this.

```
User.saveUser(newUser, function (err,user) {
        if(!err){
            res.json({state:true, msg:"data Inserted"});
        }

        else{
            res.json({state:false, msg:"data Is Not Inserted"});
        }
    });
```

In the front end, I am doing this kind of thing in the component.ts file.

```
this.userService.registerUser(user).subscribe(res=>{
      if(res.state) {
        this.flashMessage.show('You are succesfully registerded', {cssClass: 'alert-success', delay: 1000});
      }

      else{
        this.flashMessage.show('registration went wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', delay: 1000});
      }
    });
```

In the service file, I just return the response like this.

```
registerUser(user: User){
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/register', user, {headers: headers});

  }
```

When I console log the respond in the component file it gives me the right output. But when I try to access the res.state  like in the code that I have provided in above, it gives me an error saying that

```
Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You!

Comment: Please `console.log` res and copy and paste that into here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it as follows,

```
this.userService.registerUser(user).subscribe((res:any)=>{
```